# jquery click event keeps unbinding

Tags: jquery

When I run the code the click event works the first time. When I click it more then one time it seems that the click even has unbounded. How do I keep the click event bounded?

```
var Categories = function() {
        $("select[id^='CategoryListBox-']").click(
        function() {
            SelectedItem = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().load('/Categories/CategoryPicker?CatID=' + SelectedItem);

            //send CatID to the requesting page
            $('form#SubmitPost').prepend('<input id="CatID" name="CatID" type="hidden" value="' + SelectedItem + '" />');
        });
    }

    Categories();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using AJAX to load new HTML from the server and you're overwriting the existing select box with a new one. This will remove event listeners. One solution is to use `live()`:

```
$("select[id^='CategoryListBox-']").live("click", function() {
  SelectedItem = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().load('/Categories/CategoryPicker?CatID=' + SelectedItem);

  //send CatID to the requesting page
  $('form#SubmitPost').prepend('<input id="CatID" name="CatID" type="hidden" value="' + SelectedItem + '" />');
});
```

One suggestion: don't use an attribute selector like this. Give all the relevant select boxes a class like "category" and then do:

```
$("select.category").live("click", function() { ... }
```

It's much faster.

Lastly, this is a better way of creating your hidden inputs:

```
$("<input>").attr({id: "CatID", name: "CatID", type: "hidden", value: SelectedItem}).prependTo("#SubmitPost");
```

The reason being that this creates the DOM element directly rather than interpreting HTML, which again is much slower.

Comment: cletus brings up a very valid other point that you should definitely not be using a selector like that.

Comment: I have another problem. Is there a way to access the new loaded items? I can access the old items but I can't access the new items

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the click handler by replacing the dom inside of it's parent element. You can use `live` instead to always keep the binding.

Line 2 would be:

`$("select[id^='CategoryListBox-']").live('click',`

And that should do it

Comment: I have another problem. Is there a way to access the new loaded items? I can access the old items but I can't access the new items

Comment: you should ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly creating/re-creating the object and then failing to re-bind the event? I have one site where we do a fair amount of AJAX updating (using the jQuery taconite plugin), and the last thing we do is explicitly bind the click events on the newly created DOM objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you load() into parent(), you're replacing the original CategoryListBox-* element with a new one. The new one has nothing bound to it. You can either re-bind the function to the new element, which would be ugly and possibly get you into a nasty recursion situation, or you can use the .live() function to bind Categories() to any DOM element with the id of CategoryListBox-*. That would look something like:

```
$("select[id^='CategoryListBox-']").live('click', function() { [body of your Categories() function] } );
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

This will work in jQuery 1.3+. If you're using 1.2, you should upgrade or use the livequery plugin to get similar functionality.

Comment: I have another problem. Is there a way to access the new loaded items? I can access the old items but I can't access the new items